# If Quorra is injured in the physical world, will she bleed or derez?

Tags: tron-legacy, tron

In *Tron: Legacy* while in the Grid, Sam Flynn gets injured and bleeds blood. This immediately identifies him as a User instead of a Program.

Later we see Quorra get injured while in the Grid, and her arm de-rezzes. Kevin Flynn opens up her code and removes some sort of problem, and she begins to regenerate (re-rez?), soon regaining consciousness and apparent full health.

At the end of the movie, Sam and Quorra go to the physical world.

If Quorra gets injured in the physical world, will she de-rez in the same manner as she would on the Grid? Can Sam open her code to try to make a repair?

Comment: I doubt there's any canon answer to this (at least not yet). Interesting question, though.